# How to trim spaces for parameter value in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using jenkins pipeline job with parameters. when i had any trailing spaces in parameter value the job gets failed. is there any way to trim the spaces in pipeline job to avoid build failure?

Comment: why is your job failing ?

Comment: When i leave some spaces in parameter value its getting failed.

Comment: ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.

Answer (score 6):

Use the Groovy `trim()` method.  For instance, `def myTrimmedParam = params.myParam.trim()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the trim parameter:

```
string(name: 'some parameter', trim: true)
```

Comment: from which version can you use trim? I did not find it in the documentation https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters

Comment: I just tried it on my jenkins indeed it works, very nice